# Using StopInterval() in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, dom-events, slideshow

I have a slideshow that move to the next slide every 5 seconds.  It also allow the user to click a button to jump to a specific slide and continue the slideshow.  However when the buttons are clicked it spends 10 seconds on the slide instead of 5.  Any tips for how to allow to user to change slide, have it spend 5 seconds on that slide, and then go to the next are appreciated.

Javascript:

```
(function() {

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#pagenation li");
    var slides = document.querySelector("#slider ul");
    var individSlides = document.querySelectorAll("#slider ul li");
    var i = 1;
    var slideHeight = document.querySelector(".slide").clientHeight;
    var myTimer = setInterval(moveSlide, 4800);


    for (var q=0; q<buttons.length; q++) {
      (function(q) {
        buttons[q].addEventListener('click', function(){
            clearInterval(myTimer);
            slides.style.top = (0 - (slideHeight*q)) + "px";
            $(buttons).removeClass("selected");
                $(buttons[q]).addClass("selected");
                i = q;
                if (i == 2){
                    i++;
                }
                myTimer = setInterval(moveSlide, 4800);
        })
      }(q));
    }

    //Move to the next slide and repeat if at the end
    function moveSlide() {
        if(i >= individSlides.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        slides.style.top = (0 - (slideHeight*i)) + "px";
        $(buttons).removeClass("selected");
        $(buttons[i]).addClass("selected");
        i++;
    } //end MoveSlide()

})(); //end function()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Andy's Aquatics</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="mainNav">
                <li>My Tank</li>
                <li>Product Reviews</li>
                <li>Photo Gallery</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="slideWrapper">
            <div id="slider">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide" src="images/bg.png" height="200" width="650" usemap="#slide1">
                        <map name="slide1">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,650,200" href="test.html">
                        </map>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide" src="images/bg2.png" height="200" width="650"usemap="#slide2">
                        <map name="slide2">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,650,200" href="test1.html">
                        </map>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="slide" src="images/bg3.png" height="200" width="650" usemap="#slide3">
                        <map name="slide3">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,650,200" href="test2.html">
                        </map>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul id="pagenation">
                <li class ="selected">.</li>
                <li>.</li>
                <li>.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

#mainNav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

            /****** Slider *****/
#slideWrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#slider {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
}

#slider ul {
    width: 650px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

#slider li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
}

#pagenation {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
    left: 4px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 0;
}

#pagenation li{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#pagenation li:hover {
    color: #666;
}

.selected {
    color: #666
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I see you use jQuery, ... and not use it at the same time. Why? Also this is more a critique, but for a better user experience it would be nice to see some animations! Blinking images are annoying and too *flashy*!

Comment: Also I would kindly discourage you from doing such timeout trickery. Once the user hovers the gallery, you should stop any ongoing interval. That's at least how 99% of galleries work (unless it's a fullscreen gallery, but in that case the gallery stops any interval once the user hovers the thumbnails or button icons.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your logic. Let us say the current slide is the first slide (i = 0). The user clicks on the second slide (q=1).

The first thing that happens is that you clear the interval, select the slide, set i = 1 and set the timer.

Then 5 seconds later, the call to moveSlide executes and it sets the selected slide to i (which is still 1). and increments i to 2.

Another 5 seconds passes by, and now i = 2 so the last slide is selected.

There are several ways around this, but i think now that you know the issue you can figure it out on your own, your code shows you know your stuff.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you for the help. I changed the i=q to i=(q+1) in the for loop and that seems to have worked.  I still feel like the program needs some cleaning up, but it is working at the moment.  Thanks again